# message types of topics concerning map

Tags: rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am developing an android app communicating with ros, but I don't know the information about map. I have topic names but I don't know which message types should I use. I found on the Internet but failed. Here is the list of topics I need.It's better if I can know more details of those topics.

1. Move_base_simple/goal
2. nitial_pose
3. Move_base/local_costmap/inflated_obstacles
4. move_base/NavfnROS/plan
   5.move_base/local_costmap/robot_footprint
   6.move_base/local_costmap/obstacles
   Thanks a lot.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62550/message-types-of-topics-concerning-map/) by [maoqizhen](https://answers.ros.org/users/4434/maoqizhen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7 on 2013-05-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
move_base_simple/goal - geometry_msgs/PoseStamped
```

It is a topic (non-action type) on which one can post a goal if he does not want to monitor its status (success or not) after posting.

```
initialpose - geometry_msgs/PoseWithCovarianceStamped
```

It is used to re-state the current position of the robot in the map if the robot seems lost. 2d pose estimate in rviz does this.

```
Move_base/local_costmap/inflated_obstacles - nav_msgs/GridCells
```

It specifies the cells in the map grid that are considered occupied due to the inflation radius of the robot. The inflation radius of the turtlebot is mentioned in turtlebot_navigation/config/local_costmap_params.yaml

```
move_base/local_costmap/obstacles - nav_msgs/GridCells
```

It specifies the cells in the map grid that are occupied by obstacles.

```
move_base/local_costmap/robot_footprint - geometry_msgs/PolygonStamped
```

In a map, the the robot is represented as a polygon which is called 'footprint' of a robot. This topic lists the points on the circumference of the polygon that form the footprint.

```
move_base/NavfnROS/plan - nav_msgs/Path
```

Once you give a nav goal the robot marks a path along which it has to move to reach the goal point (shown as a thin gree line in rviz). This topic lists the points in the local costmap that lie on the path.

Read more [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/move_base), [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/costmap_2d), [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/amcl) and [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation).

---

Originally posted by [prasanna.kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/2416/prasanna.kumar/) with karma: 1363 on 2013-05-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1